# svn:ignore generated subfolders

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I'm always having troubles with svn:ignore, but this time I think I may be attempting something impossible.

assuming dir structure:

```
/
   /foo
   /bar
   /web
      /uploads
          /assets
          /avatars
              /fu
                  /*.jpg
              /ba
                  /*.jpg
              keepme.jpg
              keepmetoo.jpg
```

I want to be ignore all subfolders of the avatars directory but not the files of that directory (keepme.jpg, keepmetoo.jpg).

The avatar subfolders (fu, ba) are auto generated and the names cannot be predetermined, so need to completely ignore all /avatar subfolders.

Is this possible? and how?

**Edit** we would prefer not to use post-commit hooks. This is simply a matter of preference. We have a lot of well established applications and have developed a standardised way of doing things and post commit hooks simply haven't been utilized yet. We would simple prefer not to add any unnecessary additional moving parts. Frankly it is more likely we would address the directory structure (which is no small task) before considering adding post-commit hooks.

Comment: Add a bounty to your question if you want to spark some interest in it.

Comment: @ulidtko: tbh the issue is really old and I can't remember the specific of why it had to be that way. I will update the question with more specifics in the morning. As for the awkward use of VCS systems, you are correct, but from memory we had some directory layout restrictions due to the framework in use and out initial implementation. Sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889375/svn-ignore-subfolders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to store the entire lot in svn, except /avataurs/fu and avatars/ba (all avatars/xxx in fact)?

You need to initially add the remaining directory structure to svn. Use Tortoise to add the root directory, un-check the directories you do not want to add, then commit. that solves the initial problem - of not committing the offending subdirectories, all's good.

Except, the next problem is that you do not want anyone else to 'accidentally' add newly generated subdirectories - in this case, a pre-commit hook is essential. They are very simple indeed - you only need to write a quick batch file or perl script that does  aregex on the paths of the incoming files, and return 1 if any contain `".*/avatars/.*/.*"` (which will still allow new files to be added to that directory). The hook can also return text that will be displayed to the user who was adding the files. I use one to prevent files being checked in with a file extension on a ban list (eg .obj etc).

If the avatar subdirs never make it into SVN then you'll never check them out - obviously - and your job is done!

---

Here's a copy of my pre-commit.cmd hook file. Just drop it into your hooks directory (on windows) and you're good to go.

```
@echo off

svnlook changed -t %2 %1 > c:\temp\pre-commit.txt

findstr /G:"%1\hooks\ignore-matches.txt"  c:\temp\pre-commit.txt > c:\temp\precommit-bad.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 exit 0

echo disallowed file extension >> c:\temp\precommit-bad.txt

type c:\temp\precommit-bad.txt 1>&2
exit 1
```

the ignore-matches.txt file contains lines like this:

```
^[^D].*\.obj$
```

anything that matches the entries in the ignore-matches.txt file means the commit is rejected,the user will have to try again, correctly this time.

Comment: How portable are pre-commit hooks? I'm not familiar with them myself so apologies for the n00bish questions to follow. Do the hook scripts go in the repo config itself or is each user responsible for setting up the hooks in their local checkout. I ask because we use a mixture of tortisesvn on windows and commandline svn in ubuntu.

Comment: they are a server-side, repo-configuration-type thing. Look at your repo, you'll see a hooks directory with some sample templates already in there just waiting to be renamed to executable script. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks

Answer (score 1):

In short, with config-only pure SVN this is not possible.  But you have some options for settings those properties, and for checking them, like

- beefing up your avatar auto-generation tool,
- invoke a batch file updating SVN settings after the auto-generation,
- invoke a batch file updating SVN settings before the commit.

On the server side, you can

- reject commits on pre-commit if they do not follow the rules,
- automatically update the settings on the post-commit hook,
- or require smart developers and only check in the CI system.

First, I would recommend to automatically update the svn:ignore property after the auto-generation of the folders. The easiest way would be to invoke a batch-file after doing the generation.  The batch-file itself would be simple:

```
@echo off
echo.>~svnignore
dir /b /aD >~svnignore
svn propset svn:ignore --file ~svnignore .
del ~svnignore
```

Of course, the file `~svnignore` should be a filename which you can guarantee to not use for anything else.  If this is invoked automatically upon the generation, this should work for everybody.

Second, I would recommend to check for the integrity either in the pre-commit hook.  Doing it in the post-commit may be acceptable, doing it in the continuous integration system will definitely be too late.

Finally, you have another option, though I would not recommend going this route:  As you tagged the question with `tortoisesvn` I assume, you use this tool.  This provides you with the additional option to use a client-side pre-commit hook.  For this, go into the TortoiseSVN Settings dialog.  In the left-side tree you will find an entry *Hook Scripts*, where you can configure some executables (like batch-files...) to be executed upon certain times, like at *pre-commit* time.

The disadvantage of this is that you practically break all console usage of SVN, and if you want to have some automation for some builds/tags etc., this will be worthless.

Comment: We use both tortisesvn and command line directly in the ubuntu shell so as you noted the last option isn't usable. Editing the svn:ignore when the auto generation is run isn't viable either as these directories are deleted and created a number of times a day. And sadly no matter how smart the developer, everyone makes a mistake eventually :) I do believe pre-commit hooks may be the way to go

Comment: How portable are pre-commit hooks? I'm not familiar with them myself so apologies for the n00bish questions to follow. Do the hook scripts go in the repo config itself or is each user responsible for setting up the hooks in their local checkout. I ask because we use a mixture of tortisesvn on windows and commandline svn in ubuntu.

Comment: First, I want to add that running that "set-svn-ignore" script several times a day is no problem -- it is finished in virtually no time.  Second, the hook scripts are server-side, part of the repo config, and are system specific (cmd vs. bash), but by using a unix shell (and on windows use mingw/msys/etc.) + svnlook, the system specific part gets irrelevant.  I'll leave it to @gbjbaanb, as vs. me he concentrated on that part and has an example already there.

Answer (score -2):

Setting up a [start-commit hook](http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/version-control-with-subversion-1.6/svn.ref.reposhooks.start-commit.html) could be a solution.