# SVN: Ignore subfolders

Tags: svn, svnignore

I have a folder say: `/user_files`, which I want to include in SVN, but there are additional folders underneath it which I don't want to include.

Is there a way to use `svn:ignore` to ignore anything in a folder even if that parent folder is included in the repos?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this to ignore everything in the user_files directory:

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*' user_files
```

This sets the `svn:ignore` property to `*` on the `user_files` directory, which effectively causes svn to ignore every untracked file in this directory.

Then you have to commit the directory on which you set the property, and update other working copies.

Comment: Sweet thanks. If I do propset on a server, do I also need to do it on my local machine?

Comment: BTW if I run: svn propset svn:ignore graphic_novel_images '*'  I get '*' is not under version control

Comment: You need to do it on a working copy of the repository (a checkout for the repository); then commit that directory. Then every up-to-date working copy (including the one on your local machine) will have to property too.

Comment: do `svn propset svn:ignore '*' graphic_novel_images`

Answer (score 6):

`.svnignore` doesn't stop you from adding things - it just suppresses them being reported in `svn stat`.  You could put `/user_files` in your `.svnignore` and then force-add the things you want to add from there.